# Exception in SqlConnection constructor causing exception in finalize

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, sqlconnection, finalizer

I have the following code:

```
SqlConnection ret = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

This throws a `ConfigurationException` which I catch, however, since the exception occurs in the constructor itself, the `ret` is null/unassigned, so I am not able to call `Dispose/Close` on the new instance of `SqlConnection`.

As a result, at some random time in the future, the `Finalize` method of the created (but unassigned to the `ret` variable) `SqlConnection` instance gets called (most likely from a separate thread) which throws the same `ConfigurationException` but I am not able to catch it since it occurs on a different thread. This brings the whole app down.

What is the correct coding approach to handle this situation?

P.S. The exception is because of an unexpected section in the `machine.config` file, but we need to handle it via code instead of asking customers to fix the `machine.config` file.

Comment: Very tricky situation. Do you know why the ConfigurationException is occuring in the first place? Did you also try wrapping the code inside a using {} block?

Comment: It's not that `ret` is null - it's that it never gets assigned *anything*. When you talk about "the Finalize method of the instance" do you mean the finalizer of your `SqlConnection`, or of your own class? If it's the finalizer of the `SqlConnection`, that's a bug in `SqlConnection` itself. If it's your finalizer, that's your bug... we need more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The Finalizer of SQLConnection gets called. I have edited the question with this and some more info about the exception.

Comment: Post the connection string. Version of sql Server you are using. The call stack could help too.

Comment: Sharing a single `SqlConnection` over multiple threads is not very safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's  reasonable for an issue in the `machine.config` file to mean that an app simply can't run. If your system-wide configuration is broken, you (the owner of that broken configuration) *should* fix it. Not all failures *can* be properly handled in code.

I would recommend not trying to work around this, but to *detect* it early on, and abort in as clean a way as possible. If you're aware that this can be an issue, you might want to explicitly check for it - in as error-free a way as you can find - immediately on startup, and fail with a really good error message and advice. As a user, I would generally far rather something failed early with clear steps for fixing the issue than trying to limp on regardless, but doing a poor job due to being in a fundamentally hostile environment.

You should *also* report the issue to Microsoft, as the `SqlConnection` finalizer throwing an exception when the constructor didn't even complete is very nasty.